# Keylogger and mousetracker: should I use non-blocking I/O?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mouseevent, nonblocking

I'm writing a simple keylogger/mouselogger in C/C++ for Windows. To do that, I use the Win32 functions `LowLevelMouseProc` and `LowLevelKeyboardProc`.

If relevant, here is a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/julien-h/7e045c0c66a9af1ef858fc84d1c3ac31) with my code, which is ultra-elementary: define the event callback and register it along with a callback for SIGINT. I'll add a summarized version at the end of the question.

**My question is the following**: in order to minimize overhead, how should I save these events to disk?

Answers in both C or C++ are welcome.

Is it a good practice to simply write to a buffered file each time I get a new event and let the file handle flushing when the buffer is full? I heard about non-blocking I/O but microsoft's doc says that there is an additional overhead. And finally, I'm not sure wether I should create a second thread for this.

I'd like to use some sort of buffering to avoid many little disk I/O. Ideally I would write to disk once before my process is killed. But I have no idea how to achieve this.

CODE:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

HHOOK handle;
LRESULT CALLBACK lowLevelMouseProc(
    _In_ int    nCode,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* lp = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
        // Best way to save pt.x and pt.y to disk?
        printf("%d %d \n", lp->pt.x, lp->pt.y);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    handle = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE_LL, &lowLevelMouseProc, NULL, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0));
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(handle)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Links aren't sufficient.

Comment: @PasserBy done.

Comment: *"Ideally I would write to disk once before my process is killed."* - As implemented, your process can never terminate gracefully. The call to `UnhookWindowsHookEx` never runs. As for asynchronous I/O, that's a viable option to offload disk access off of your thread of execution. You'll need to make sure that your data is live during the entire execution of the asynchronous I/O, though, and implement an appropriate resource management scheme.

Comment: @IInspectable, don’t « GetMesage » return 0 when the computer is shutdown?

Comment: I don't know whether it does. If it does, then that is not the time to perform lengthy operations (like flushing data to disk). A simple change can turn your application into one, that can gracefully shutdown: Replace the message loop implementation with a call to `MessageBox`. Once that is dismissed, the program can perform cleanup (or whatever else it needs to do).

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the suggestion! I'm new to windows API and currently in the middle of reading the doc. What could I do to shutdown gracefully without opening any windows? I don't want to have a MessageBox opened all the time on my PC.

Comment: One solution could be to register a global hotkey ([RegisterHotkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey)), and create a [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) to receive the notification. Terminate your process from there. That's pretty much all you can do if you don't want any visible UI.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks, i'll look into that :-) 
Any suggestion for the original question?

Comment: Offload the slow operation (writing to disk). [Asynchronous I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o) is a viable solution, even if not entirely trivial to implement. [Coroutines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/await-enable-coroutine-support) work too, if you are willing to use C++20 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 buffers. One for writing, one for reading (flushing to disk). Once some condition is met (buffer full, program shutdown, ...), swap the buffers and start flushing to disk in a seperate thread.

This might look something like:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <atomic>

struct Point
{
    long x, y;
};

class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(std::string _file = "log.txt", const size_t _buffer_size = 100000) : buffer_size(_buffer_size), file(_file)
    {
        points1.reserve(_buffer_size);
        points2.reserve(_buffer_size);
    }

    void write(Point p)
    {
        buf->push_back(p);
        if (buf->size() >= buffer_size && !thread_running.load())
            to_disk();
    }

private:
    const size_t buffer_size;
    const std::string file;
    std::atomic<bool> thread_running{ false };
    std::vector<Point> points1, points2;
    std::vector<Point> *buf = &points1, *other = &points2;


    void swap_buffer()
    {
        std::swap(buf, other);
    }

    void to_disk()
    {
        swap_buffer();
        auto tmp_buf = other;
        auto tmp_file = file;
        auto tmp_flag = &thread_running;
        auto fn = [tmp_buf, tmp_file, tmp_flag]() {
            tmp_flag->store(true);
            std::fstream f(tmp_file, std::ios::app);
            for (auto &v : *tmp_buf)
                f << v.x << ' ' << v.y << '\n';
            tmp_buf->clear();
            tmp_flag->store(false);
        };
        std::thread t(fn);
        t.detach();
    }
};
Buffer buffer("log.txt");


HHOOK handle;
LRESULT CALLBACK lowLevelMouseProc(
    _In_ int    nCode,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* lp = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
        buffer.write({ lp->pt.x, lp->pt.y });
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    handle = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE_LL, &lowLevelMouseProc, NULL, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0));
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the buffer gets written to disk when a certain size limit is reached. This could be further optimized, by not checking the size on every write for example.

Note: In this example, error handling is omitted and the lifetime of the internal buffers should be managed accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Fubert, this looks very nice. Just to be sure that I understand the implications of your code: what potential bottleneck or errorcase do you anticipate?

Comment: I anticipate data races, the usual kind you get when using multithreading without synchronization or atomic operations. What's more, you don't even need multithreading when using asynchronous I/O. This implementation provides a performance pessimization and undefined behavior. Don't use.

Comment: Hmm in that case please edit your answer to state what potential issues are and how we can make this code "safe".

Comment: @Julien__ In general, don't copy/paste code from the interwebs without understanding it. It was more meant to showcase the idea of using multiple buffers and switching between them with a pointer, not a full implementation of a buffer. One problem with the ´buffer´ is, for example, that the background thread might outlive the buffer, which will lead to UB. Perfomance pessimization? Maybe, compared to what? Undefined behavior? I don't see it (in this example). To be clear, ´buffer´ in this example is not intended to be 'thread-safe' (used by multiple threads).

Comment: @Fubert you're right, that's why I'm asking for pitfalls. If I use your idea, I must make sure that I understand it fully. Which is why I asked you for more details. I'll be happy to write the necessary code, but I must know what to look for. An exhaustive list of the things I should improve would be awesome.

Comment: @Julien__ I can't give you an exhaustive list, it depends on your application. Pretty much everything could be improved. If it's as simple as logging some coordinates, why not use a std::string and write that to disk every now and then? Or look into other api's that provide i/o functionality, like IInspectable mentioned.

Comment: @Julien__ Think about what happens when you exit your program/scope, in this example some garbage may be written to your file or you run into an exception (If the thread outlives the buffer). In a real program you have to manage the lifetime of your objects and probably don't want to just detach the thread.